# Facebook like button once clicked on one page applies to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xfbml, social-media

I'm trying to add facebook like to a site using xfbml, I've been following the guidelines from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
The page is based on JSP's and I'm doing the xfbml setup at the end of a header.jsp file which is included at the start of the body tag. I'm providing meta tags using open graph for title, description, and image, but these are parameters passed into the header.

For some reason, the facebook like button once clicked for one page then appears to be liked for all other pages in the same context. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you dynamically changing the data-href attribute on the button for each page on which it appears?

Comment: Yeah, I'm generating a short url for each article/post and using that in the href, i.e.:`<div class="fb-like">
 <fb:like href="<%=shortUrl%>" send="false" width="25" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light" ></fb:like>
</div>`

Comment: I have the same behavior with Google's +1 button at the moment too...

Comment: I wonder if the short url might be the problem. Have you tried using the actual requested url instead? And for clarification, what do you mean by "other pages in the same context"?

Comment: It seems that the way we are generating the short urls is producing duplicates...oops!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="fb-root" ></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Try Using This.